# Sphinx link to python standard library documentation

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

In order to be able to reference standard python documentation I have added to my config file the following:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
master_doc = 'index'
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.intersphinx']
intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3.6', None)}
```

I have a rst file that makes reference to a python function as:

```
See :py:func:`io.open`.
```

When the documentation is built, it correctly recognizes `io.open` as an external function, creates a link, and when I pass the mouse over it shows the message (in Python 3.6), so I believe it is somehow working.

However, the link that it uses is:

file:///C:/mylib/docs/build/python/library/io.html#io.open

instead of:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.open

Am I missing something extra in the config? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is correct configuration and syntax. I just tried it using Sphinx 3.0.x on macOS, and built docs with the correct link. Perhaps do a `make clean` to purge an old build file? Or check that you are viewing the correct file in the proper location?

Comment: @StevePiercy Just did but there is no change. I am using Sphinx v1.6.6 on Win10. I also added the rest of the config file, not sure if the other part of the setup conflicts with intersphinx.

Comment: I don't see an issue with the config. Try upgrading Sphinx, else you can search the Sphinx issue tracker.

Comment: Do you actually have a local build of the standard documentation in file:///C:/mylib/docs/build/python? What happens if you delete it?

Comment: @mzjn No I don't. It creates a link to a non existing file.